# Mockito cannot mock this class : Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, byte-buddy

For a university exam i was given to test some of apache bookkeeper classes/methods and in doing so i thought to use mockito in my parameterized test.
Test without mockito works fine but when i try to mock an interface i get this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.apache.bookkeeper.discover.RegistrationManager.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Ubuntu
JVM vendor version : 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 4.15.0-112-generic


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

    at org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest.<init>(BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1817)
    at org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest.<init>(BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder.appendMostSpecific(java.util.Collection)'
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:83)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    ... 43 more
```

Here the test class i'm writing:

```
package org.apache.bookkeeper.client;


import org.apache.bookkeeper.conf.ServerConfiguration;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.discover.RegistrationManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.discover.ZKRegistrationManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.meta.LayoutManager;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.BookKeeperClusterTestCase;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.ZooKeeperCluster;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.test.ZooKeeperUtil;
import org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper;
import org.apache.zookeeper.data.ACL;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@RunWith(value= Parameterized.class)
public class BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest extends BookKeeperClusterTestCase {

    private boolean result;
    private ServerConfiguration conf;
    private String confType ;

    private static final int numOfBookies = 2;
    private final int lostBookieRecoveryDelayInitValue = 1800;

    @Mock
    RegistrationManager mockedRM = mock(RegistrationManager.class) ;
 

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTestParameters(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{

                //last parameter states if the method rm.initNewCluster() called inside
                // BookKeeperAdmin.initNewCluster(conf) must be mocked or not

                {true ,  "new" },
                {false , "null" },
                {false , "wrong"},
                {false , "mock"},  //caso di test introdotto per portare la branch coverage al 100%
                                    // entrando nella clausola catch del metodo initNewCluste()

        });

    }



    public BookKeeperAdminInitNewClusterTest(boolean result , String conf) throws Exception {

        super(numOfBookies, 480);
        baseConf.setLostBookieRecoveryDelay(lostBookieRecoveryDelayInitValue);
        baseConf.setOpenLedgerRereplicationGracePeriod(String.valueOf(30000));
        setAutoRecoveryEnabled(true);

        this.result = result;
        this.confType = conf;


    }

    @Test
    public void testInitNewCluster() throws Exception {

        boolean realResult ;


        if(confType == "null"){

            this.conf = null;

        }else if( confType == "wrong"){

            this.conf = new ServerConfiguration().setMetadataServiceUri("zk+hierarchical://127.0.0.1/ledgers");

        }else if(confType == "new") {

            this.conf = new ServerConfiguration(baseConf);
            String ledgersRootPath = "/testledgers";
            this.conf.setMetadataServiceUri(newMetadataServiceUri(ledgersRootPath));

        }else if(confType == "mock"){

          

            when(mockedRM.initNewCluster()).thenThrow(new Exception());

        }


        try {

            realResult = BookKeeperAdmin.initNewCluster(conf);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            realResult = false ;
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        assertEquals(result,realResult);
    }

}
```

And here the interface i'm trying to mock:

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.apache.bookkeeper.discover;

import org.apache.bookkeeper.bookie.BookieException;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.common.annotation.InterfaceAudience.LimitedPrivate;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.common.annotation.InterfaceStability.Evolving;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.versioning.Version;
import org.apache.bookkeeper.versioning.Versioned;

/**
 * Registration manager interface, which a bookie server will use to do the registration process.
 */
@LimitedPrivate
@Evolving
public interface RegistrationManager extends AutoCloseable {

    /**
     * Registration Listener on listening the registration state.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface RegistrationListener {

        /**
         * Signal when registration is expired.
         */
        void onRegistrationExpired();

    }

    @Override
    void close();

    /**
     * Return the cluster instance id.
     *
     * @return the cluster instance id.
     */
    String getClusterInstanceId() throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Registering the bookie server as <i>bookieId</i>.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @param readOnly whether to register it as writable or readonly
     * @param serviceInfo information about services exposed by the Bookie
     * @throws BookieException when fail to register a bookie.
     */
    void registerBookie(String bookieId, boolean readOnly, BookieServiceInfo serviceInfo) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Unregistering the bookie server as <i>bookieId</i>.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @param readOnly whether to register it as writable or readonly
     * @throws BookieException when fail to unregister a bookie.
     */
    void unregisterBookie(String bookieId, boolean readOnly) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Checks if Bookie with the given BookieId is registered as readwrite or
     * readonly bookie.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @return returns true if a bookie with bookieid is currently registered as
     *          readwrite or readonly bookie.
     * @throws BookieException
     */
    boolean isBookieRegistered(String bookieId) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Write the cookie data, which will be used for verifying the integrity of the bookie environment.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @param cookieData cookie data
     * @throws BookieException when fail to write cookie
     */
    void writeCookie(String bookieId, Versioned<byte[]> cookieData) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Read the cookie data, which will be used for verifying the integrity of the bookie environment.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @return versioned cookie data
     * @throws BookieException when fail to read cookie
     */
    Versioned<byte[]> readCookie(String bookieId) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Remove the cookie data.
     *
     * @param bookieId bookie id
     * @param version version of the cookie data
     * @throws BookieException when fail to remove cookie
     */
    void removeCookie(String bookieId, Version version) throws BookieException;

    /**
     * Prepare ledgers root node, availableNode, readonly node..
     *
     * @return Returns true if old data exists, false if not.
     */
    boolean prepareFormat() throws Exception;

    /**
     * Initializes new cluster by creating required znodes for the cluster. If
     * ledgersrootpath is already existing then it will error out.
     *
     * @return returns true if new cluster is successfully created or false if it failed to initialize.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    boolean initNewCluster() throws Exception;

    /**
     * Do format boolean.
     *
     * @return Returns true if success do format, false if not.
     */
    boolean format() throws Exception;

    /**
     * Nukes existing cluster metadata.
     *
     * @return returns true if cluster metadata is successfully nuked
     *          or false if it failed to nuke the cluster metadata.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    boolean nukeExistingCluster() throws Exception;
}
```

2 notes:

- i posted also my test class code to be sure there is no conflict in using a parameterized test and mockito
- from what i was able to understand the problem is byteBuddy more than mockito itself but i don't know how to fix this.

Mockito version i'm using is 3.0.0
Bytebuddy version is 1.9.3

I hope you can help me,
have a good day all :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [this bug report](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1606), you might have a version incompatibility problem with ByteBuddy and Mockito.

Try to either downgrade Mockito to version 2.23 or upgrade ByteBuddy to version 1.97.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how can i downgrade mockito to version 2.23? I tried to set it in pom.xml and removing the library dependencies in my modules structure but when i try to use mockito intellij tells me to add the maven dependency to Mockito-core-3.0.Sorry if it's a dumb question but it' s a big project i have imported so it's  bit difficult to me understand how to handle it!

Comment: Might be that the newer version is coming from some other POM or from cache. In IntelliJ, you could try invalidating the IDE's caches (File->Invalidate caches) and also reimporting all Maven projects from Maven settings.

Comment: Ty sir i try and post you an update! In the meanwhile ty for your time/kindness.

Comment: Great man cleaning cache was the solution! Ty very much. Can i ask you, if you know, why if i mock an interface it's implementation it's not mocked too? Ty for your great help!

Comment: Nice to hear that you got it working. I'm not sure what you mean with that question exactly. Anything that you mock with `mock()` will essentially become an "empty implementation" of the target interface/class (meaning that the methods don't do anything and only return primitive default values or `null`s for any object return values). You then need to provide the needed (mocked) implementation yourself using Mockito's `doReturn(...).when(...)` construct. Maybe you could ask another question if you're having difficulties working with mocks?