# adding Mockito gives logging error when running a test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using JUnit 5 in my Spring project and would like to do some mocking using Mockito. So I've I added a couple Mockito dependencies: mockito-core 2.21.0 and mockito-junit-jupiter 4.0.0.

Then based on some guidance I found somewhere I added this to my very simple test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

But when I run the test I get this confounding error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.
    getMockitoLogger()Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockitoLogger;
...
```

But I'm not using the MockitoLogger class anywhere, or at least not explicitly. So what could cause this strangeness?

Comment: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1604 try mockito-core 2.24.0

Comment: Wow, that did get me past that error. But now I get: "Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes." Yet the class I'm mocking is neither.

Comment: Interestingly, I then found this answer to a question regarding the "Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes", which includes github that suggests switching to mockito-core-2.23.0. When I do that my mocking seems to work successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, switching to mockito-core-2.23.0 seemed to resolve this for me. I took that approach based on advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63640379/3368818) for a different issue.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to mock a method and test a method in the same class you have to use @Spy instead of @Mock. Then you should remove the @BeforeEach code block. Additionally you have to call the method you want to test.

Plz share more code, thanks